# Using ActiveAdmin with a JSON API instead of ActiveRecord Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So I understand this is "off the Rails" but I'm curious if ActiveAdmin can be used without actual models. Basically, there's been a decision made that all of our applications have to have their administrative resources hosted in a centralized application, w/o access to the various databases. This decouples the actual models from the admin application. Each of the client applications provide an external facing RESTful interface that the admin application is expected to leverage.

I have been looking for an admin interface tool to reduce(eliminate) the amount of view code that has to be written.   I've used ActiveAdmin previously in a more standard manner and really love what it buys us.

Is this feasible? Can ActiveAdmin be made to load/create/save/etc through a JSON API rather than directly to the database with ActiveRecord?

If so, can anyone point me at documentation or examples that show how to do it? I've not been allotted the spike time to reverse engineer ActiveAdmin and figure out what I can do.

Also, if anyone has used a different administrative interface tool that can handle the JSON interface, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Check [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource), it would let you have similar objects to activerecord ones, but works with API's, I'm currently facing the same problem and probably go with that option. The idea is that an ActiveResource objects interacts with a API instead of a Database, you can have your relations, belongs_to, has_many, methods and validations there, and have pretty much the same workflow. regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've not read of anyone doing this and I suspect ActiveAdmin is not flexible enough. There was a good presentation at Railsconf 2019 on wrapping APIs with ActiveModel (at Square, search YouTube) and you might be able to build ActiveAdmin compatible resources that way. However, I would first look at https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin as it is already designed to work with different backends, though it is not as feature rich.